# Cohomological functor on a triangulated category necessarily comes from a t-structure?

Tags: homological-algebra, triangulated-categories

Let $\mathcal{T}$ be a triangulated category, and $H:\mathcal{T}\to\mathcal{A}$ a cohomological functor to an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$. Does there exist a t-structure on $\mathcal{T}$ for which $H$ is the cohomological functor to the heart of this t-structure?

Perhaps conditions are needed on $\mathcal{T}$, or $\mathcal{A}$, or $H$.

I was thinking that one could take the aisle to be $U=\{a\in \mathcal{T}\mid H(a[i])\cong 0, i\in \Bbb Z_{\geq 1}\}$ and coaisle to be $V=\{a\in\mathcal{T}\mid H(a[i])\cong 0, i\in \Bbb Z_{\leq -1}\}$, which are shift closed in the appropriate sense. I wasn't sure why orthogonality would hold though. In particular, although for $a\in U$ and $b\in V[-1]$, and any map $f:a\to b$ where we extend to a distinguished triangle $a\stackrel{f}\to b\to c(f)\to \Sigma a$ we have that $H(f)=0$, I can't see why $f$ would need to be zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cohomological functor that comes from a $t$-structure will vanish on all nonzero shifts of the heart.

However, a cohomological functor may not vanish on any nonzero objects. For example, let $\mathcal{T}=D^b(\mathcal{A})$ be the bounded derived category of an abelian category, and
$$F(X)=\bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}H^i(X).$$